# How to access to parent widget elements?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt5

I want to access to the parent widget elements from child widget.
The parent widget has `Qlistwidget`, I want to transfer the selected item from parent to child widget.

[image]

I have tried to make a simple example to access to the parent window title, then after that I will try to access to selected item in `qlistWidget`.

But the first trying to access the parent widget window title has been failed.

```
ui->lineEdit->setText(this->parentWidget()->windowTitle());
```

**Now My inquiry is:**

- **Firstly, how to access to the parent widget elements like window title.**
- **Secondly, how to access to the selected item in `qlistWidget` that in
  parent widget**

Comment: First related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435517/how-to-access-parent-widget-pointer-in-qt) contains similar mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parent()` function to get a parent of your `QObject`. To get children of your parent,  use QObject's `findChildren` function, passing object name or type as template.
`QListWidget` class has `selectedItems()` member function, will return selected item. 
Use `qobject_cast` to cast your `QObject` pointers to needed class.

Answer (score 1):

You can access parent's elements, but it's not a right way to go. You should control children instead. Add method to your dialog to set a text, use it to initialize the dialog when you open it and every time `QListWidget` selected item is changed.

This approach allows to lessen amount of dependencies, avoid an interdependency, use the dialog in other places of your program.

**Not for use but for knowledge:**

> Firstly, how to access to the parent widget elements like window title.

You do it correctly. Most probably you didn't pass a parent to the constructor of the dialog.

```
Dialog* dialog = new QDialog(this);
```

> Secondly, how to access to the selected item in qlistWidget that in parent widget

a) You can use `dynamic_cast` or `qobject_cast`  to cast the parent widget to the exact class of the window and use public methods to obtain all needed information.

b) You can inherit your window from an interface with needed methods for obtaining the data and pass this interface to the dialog.